# How can I write derived Ruby classes that call a base class's method when they're defined?

Tags: ruby, class

Let's say I have this class:

```
class ComponentLibrary
  def self.register(klass); ...; end
end
```

And suppose I also have this base class:

```
class BaseComponent
  ComponentLibrary.register self
end
```

How can I write derivative classes, with a minimum of repetition, that will register themselves with `ComponentLibrary` when they're defined? (In other words, I'd prefer not to keep writing `ComponentLibrary.register self` everywhere.)

Just to be clear, I'm talking about writing other classes like:

```
class RedComponent < BaseComponent
  # ...
end

class BlueComponent < BaseComponent
  # ...
end
```

but I don't want to write `ComponentLibrary.register self` for each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class BaseComponent
  def self.inherited(base)
    ComponentLibrary.register(base)
  end
end

class RedComponent < BaseComponent
end
```

Something along these lines might work for you.

Edit: changed to #inherited.

Comment: This won't work, because the module is only included once -- when BaseComponent is initially defined. As soon as you make a new class (try e.g. `class DerivedComponent < BaseComponent`) it breaks.